# Coffeescript + Browserify + Gulp + Uglify

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gulp, browserify

been at this one pretty much all day and I can't figure out how to get this working properly. As the topic suggests, I'm having a hell of a time getting this setup working.

I have a project written in Coffeescript using Browserify. I'm trying to write some Gulp build tasks that will Uglify the output for production....pretty standard.

Here's my current setup for my `gulpfile`:

```js
gulp = require 'gulp'
browserify = require 'browserify'
source = require 'vinyl-source-stream'
buffer = require 'vinyl-buffer'
uglify = require 'gulp-uglify'

# Bundle task
gulp.task('bundle', ->

  browserify(
    entries: ['./client/start.coffee']
    extensions: ['.coffee']
  )

  # Apply transforms and bundle
  .transform('coffeeify')
  .bundle()
  .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
  .pipe(buffer())
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'))
)

# Run the tasks
gulp.task('default', ['bundle'])
```

Now this code here works fine for the most part. Running the task properly bundles everything, and then it runs Uglify, resulting in a minified `bundle.js` file. The problem is when I run my sample HTML page with the JS linked in....I see this error in the console:

```js
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[ÂªÂµÂºÃ€-Ã–Ã˜-Ã¶Ã¸-ËË†-Ë‘Ë -Ë¤Ë¬Ë®Í°-Í´Í¶Í·Íº-Í½Î†Îˆ-ÎŠÎŒÎŽ-Î¡Î£-ÏµÏ·-ÒÒŠ-Ô§Ô±-Õ–Õ™Õ¡-Ö‡×-×ª×°-×²Ø -ÙŠÙ®Ù¯Ù±-Û“Û•Û¥Û¦Û®Û¯Ûº-Û¼Û¿ÜÜ’-Ü¯Ý-Þ¥Þ±ßŠ-ßªß´ßµßºà €-à •à šà ¤à ¨à¡€-à¡˜à¢ à¢¢-à¢¬à¤„-à¤¹à¤½à¥à¥˜-à¥¡à¥±-à¥·à¥¹-à¥¿à¦…-à¦Œà¦à¦à¦“-à¦¨à¦ª-à¦°à¦²à¦¶-à¦¹à¦½à§Žà§œà§à§Ÿ-à§¡à§°à§±à¨…-à¨Šà¨à¨à¨“-à¨¨à¨ª-à¨°à¨²à¨³à¨µà¨¶à¨¸à¨¹à©™-à©œà©žà©²-à©´àª…-àªàª-àª‘àª“-àª¨àªª-àª°àª²àª³àªµ-àª¹àª½à«à« à«¡à¬…-à¬Œà¬à¬à¬“-à¬¨à¬ª-à¬°à¬²à¬³à¬µ-à¬¹à¬½à­œà­à­Ÿ-à­¡à­±à®ƒà®…-à®Šà®Ž-à®à®’-à®•à®™à®šà®œà®žà®Ÿà®£à®¤à®¨-à®ªà®®-à®¹à¯à°…-à°Œà°Ž-à°à°’-à°¨à°ª-à°³à°µ-à°¹à°½à±˜à±™à± à±¡à²…-à²Œà²Ž-à²à²’-à²¨à²ª-à²³à²µ-à²¹à²½à³žà³ à³¡à³±à³²à´…-à´Œà´Ž-à´à´’-à´ºà´½àµŽàµ àµ¡àµº-àµ¿à¶…-à¶–à¶š-à¶±à¶³-à¶»à¶½à·€-à·†à¸-à¸°à¸²à¸³à¹€-à¹†àºàº‚àº„àº‡àºˆàºŠàºàº”-àº—àº™-àºŸàº¡-àº£àº¥àº§àºªàº«àº­-àº°àº²àº³àº½à»€-à»„à»†à»œ-à»Ÿà¼€à½€-à½‡à½‰-à½¬à¾ˆ-à¾Œá€€-á€ªá€¿á-á•áš-áá¡á¥á¦á®-á°áµ-á‚á‚Žá‚ -áƒ…áƒ‡áƒáƒ-áƒºáƒ¼-á‰ˆá‰Š-á‰á‰-á‰–á‰˜á‰š-á‰á‰ -áŠˆáŠŠ-áŠáŠ-áŠ°áŠ²-áŠµáŠ¸-áŠ¾á‹€á‹‚-á‹…á‹ˆ-á‹–á‹˜-áŒáŒ’-áŒ•áŒ˜-ášáŽ€-áŽáŽ -á´á-á™¬á™¯-á™¿áš-áššáš -á›ªá›®-á›°áœ€-áœŒáœŽ-áœ‘áœ -áœ±á€-á‘á -á¬á®-á°áž€-áž³áŸ—áŸœá  -á¡·á¢€-á¢¨á¢ªá¢°-á£µá¤€-á¤œá¥-á¥­á¥°-á¥´á¦€-á¦«á§-á§‡á¨€-á¨–á¨ -á©”áª§á¬…-á¬³á­…-á­‹á®ƒ-á® á®®á®¯á®º-á¯¥á°€-á°£á±-á±á±š-á±½á³©-á³¬á³®-á³±á³µá³¶á´€-á¶¿á¸€-á¼•á¼˜-á¼á¼ -á½…á½ˆ-á½á½-á½—á½™á½›á½á½Ÿ-á½½á¾€-á¾´á¾¶-á¾¼á¾¾á¿‚-á¿„á¿†-á¿Œá¿-á¿“á¿–-á¿›á¿ -á¿¬á¿²-á¿´á¿¶-á¿¼â±â¿â‚-â‚œâ„‚â„‡â„Š-â„“â„•â„™-â„â„¤â„¦â„¨â„ª-â„­â„¯-â„¹â„¼-â„¿â……-â…‰â…Žâ… -â†ˆâ°€-â°®â°°-â±žâ± -â³¤â³«-â³®â³²â³³â´€-â´¥â´§â´­â´°-âµ§âµ¯â¶€-â¶–â¶ -â¶¦â¶¨-â¶®â¶°-â¶¶â¶¸-â¶¾â·€-â·†â·ˆ-â·Žâ·-â·–â·˜-â·žâ¸¯ã€…-ã€‡ã€¡-ã€©ã€±-ã€µã€¸-ã€¼ã-ã‚–ã‚-ã‚Ÿã‚¡-ãƒºãƒ¼-ãƒ¿ã„…-ã„­ã„±-ã†Žã† -ã†ºã‡°-ã‡¿ã€-ä¶µä¸€-é¿Œê€€-ê’Œê“-ê“½ê”€-ê˜Œê˜-ê˜Ÿê˜ªê˜«ê™€-ê™®ê™¿-êš—êš -ê›¯êœ—-êœŸêœ¢-êžˆêž‹-êžŽêž-êž“êž -êžªêŸ¸-ê ê ƒ-ê …ê ‡-ê Šê Œ-ê ¢ê¡€-ê¡³ê¢‚-ê¢³ê£²-ê£·ê£»ê¤Š-ê¤¥ê¤°-ê¥†ê¥ -ê¥¼ê¦„-ê¦²ê§ê¨€-ê¨¨ê©€-ê©‚ê©„-ê©‹ê© -ê©¶ê©ºêª€-êª¯êª±êªµêª¶êª¹-êª½ê«€ê«‚ê«›-ê«ê« -ê«ªê«²-ê«´ê¬-ê¬†ê¬‰-ê¬Žê¬‘-ê¬–ê¬ -ê¬¦ê¬¨-ê¬®ê¯€-ê¯¢ê°€-íž£íž°-íŸ†íŸ‹-íŸ»ï¤€-ï©­ï©°-ï«™ï¬€-ï¬†ï¬“-ï¬—ï¬ï¬Ÿ-ï¬¨ï¬ª-ï¬¶ï¬¸-ï¬¼ï¬¾ï­€ï­ï­ƒï­„ï­†-ï®±ï¯“-ï´½ïµ-ï¶ï¶’-ï·‡ï·°-ï·»ï¹°-ï¹´ï¹¶-ï»¼ï¼¡-ï¼ºï½-ï½šï½¦-ï¾¾ï¿‚-ï¿‡ï¿Š-ï¿ï¿’-ï¿—ï¿š-ï¿œ]/: Range out of order in character class
```

When I remove the `uglify()` step, it works fine...everything is just regular Javascript and the page renders....any ideas? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem when I tried to use esprima.js with browserify. I don't know whether `gulp-uglify` passes the options to `uglify`, but I had to set the following option to make it work: `uglify({output: {ascii_only:true}})`.

Comment: Wow, do people really use Coffeescript even for task runner files?

Comment: Felix, that worked. I honestly don't completely understand what that option even does, but I'm glad it fixed it...Thanks. Also @undefined, CoffeeScript rocks. Probably not necessary for task runner files, but we have the whole project written in it so the consistency is nice.

Comment: [gulp-streamingfy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-streamify) is another option. Here is my example gulpfile.coffee.
https://github.com/coderdojo-tokyo/web/blob/master/task/coffee.coffee

Comment: Same here, I can't really tell why this works or what the problem is. Here is a longer discussion: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/54

Comment: That mess of characters makes me think, that one of the source files are in a different encoding than others. Maybe vinyl does not handle it well. (I use almost the same setup in my project, but not vinyl)

Comment: If the problem is resolved, please add the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in your comments, the answer is setting the ascii_only property on uglifyJS. Somewhere in your source code you're using non ascii characters that the compressor is trying to process, and that ends up causing the aforementioned error. Setting this flag converts those characters into the \uxxxxx pattern.